# number of non-homogeneous relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets with $n$ and $m$ elements respectively ($m, n ∈ \mathbb N
^∗
)$. Determine the
number of relations having the domain A and the codomain B

I was thinking about $|P(AXB)^{|AXB|}|$ so it will be $2^{(nm)^2}$

is this correct?

Comment: $|P(AXB)^{|AXB|}|$ is a not well formed formula, an incorrect expression.

Comment: And how should I think to count the number of relations?

Comment: The exponent should be outside the bars.

Comment: The notation AXB is poor.  AxB or A×B is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The number of relations is |P(A×B)|.
If you require for all a in A, exists b in B with (a,b) in the relation, then the number is less.